# Folder shared by VMPlayer from Windows 7 to Leap is write only

Tags: windows-7, permissions, opensuse, vmware-player

Short question:

A folder shared by VMPlayer from Windows 7 to Leap is write only. How can I delete files?

Long version:

**host**

- host computer is running Windows 7 Home 64, 6.1.7601, SP1
- share folder is D:\X , read-only perm is unchecked

**player**

- VMPlayer version is 12.1.0 build 3272444
- share is enable, read_only unchecked

**guest**

- guest is SUSE Leap 42.1 (`zypper dup`'s last week version)
- folder is mounted as `vmhgfs-fuse on /mnt/hgfs type fuse.vmhgfs-fuse (rw, nosuid, nodev, relatime, user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)`
- files belong to root, although created by plain user
- no entry in `/etc/fstab`

**deleting files**

- from Windows, admin privilege is required, even though my account own them
- from guest I can create files and overwrite the content, but I am unable to delete them (`permission denied`)
- file perm set to 777

What permission/action do I need to be able to delete files from guest?